# deseo que mi id de la tabla cliente pueda guardar en el id_Cliente de mi tabala mascota que es clave foranea

Tags: php, codeigniter

quisiera poder guardar el id_Cliente pues me sale que es un valor nulo y no lo puedo capturar y quisiera hacer eso no se si hacerlo con un inputo oculto o como llamarlo

controlador

```
public function insertar()
{
    if ($this->request->getMethod() == "post") {
        $this->mascota->save([
            
            'id_raza' => $this->request->getPost('id_raza'),
            'nombre' => $this->request->getPost('nombre'),
            'fechaNac' => $this->request->getPost('fechaNac'),
            'sexo' => $this->request->getPost('sexo'),
            'pelaje' => $this->request->getPost('pelaje'),
        ]);
        return redirect()->to(\base_url() . '/mascotas');
    } else {

        $raza = $this->raza->where('activo', 1)->findAll();
        $especie = $this->especie->where('activo', 1)->findAll();

        $data = ['titulo' => 'Agregar mascotas', 'raza' => $raza, 'especie' => $especie];

        echo view('header');
        echo view('nav');
        echo view('Mascotas/nuevo', $data);
        echo view('footer');
    }
}
```

modelo

```
class MascotasModel extends Model{

protected $table = 'mascota';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $returnType = 'array';
protected $useSoftDeletes = false;

protected $allowedFields = ['id_cliente', 'id_raza', 'nombre', 'fechaNac', 'sexo', 'pelaje','activo'];

protected $useTimestamps = true;
protected $createdField = 'fecha_alta';
protected $updatedField = 'fecha_update';
protected $deletedField = null;

protected $validationRules = [];
protected $validationMessages = [];
protected $skipValidation = false;}
```

esta es la imagen del cliente
[image: vista cliente]

a lo que le da en el boton azul ingresa a la mascotas que el es el dueño
[image: mascotas]

y esta es mi vista para agregar
[image: agregar]

y esta es mi tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla cliente
[image: cliente]

Comment: Donde te sale que id_cliente es nulo ?? y cual es la otra tabla que mencionas ?? las vitas en realidad no importan tanto

Comment: al momento de guardar me dice que el idcliente es nulo porque no se como capturarlo y poderlo almacenar y ese id_cliente es clave foranea del id de la tabla cliente

Comment: Pero muestra la tabla cliente también XD

Comment: ya agrege la tabla cliente

Comment: Ya ahora te falta hacer el envío del id_cliente en el formulario